# JSON Deserialization in Windows CE 6 with C# to Dictionary or Dictionary-like object

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

I'm trying to decode JSON from a CakePHP web service on Windows CE 6 in C#. An example of the JSON is:

```
"{
    "response":
    [
        {
            "Asset":
            {
                "name":"La Riviera","assetnumber":"16151","assettype":"Art","assignedlocation":"HOUSTON","currentlocation":"HOUSTON","properties":
                {
                    "Tag ID":"2331221","Last Seen":"","Status":"MISSING","Sold":"0","Layaway":"0","Artist":"Corbiere","Size":"80x80 cm","Calibration Date":""
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Asset":
            {
                "name":"Port de Centuri-edit","assetnumber":"16150","assettype":"Art","assignedlocation":"HOUSTON","currentlocation":"HOUSTON","properties":
                {
                    "Tag ID":"3741923","Last Seen":"","Status":"MISSING","Sold":"1","Layaway":"0","Artist":"Corbiere","Size":"80x80 cm","Calibration Date":"2013-01-12"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}"
```

I'd like to get this into a Dictionary-like object, perhaps Dictionary so that it can be accessed like

```
string name = json["response"][0]["Asset"]["name"];
```

I'm able to do this on the PC using JSON.net's LINQ JObject class and JObject.Parse, however these don't seem to work on CE. Any suggestions for a library that will do this? I'd rather not have to build specific classes for the JSON to be stuffed into for each and every situation.

Comment: try to revise your question :)

Comment: There is a version of JSON.net that does in fact work with .NET CF 3.5 that ran on CE6. So this solved the problem.